# Relative path names - Unknown directories up in DOS prompt?

Tags: windows

For relative paths, i know:
    ./ is of this directory
   ../ is 1 directory up
../../ is 2 directories up etc

Is it possible to keep going up until you reach a specified directory?

Basically my problem is that a file is compiled by two different tools, and the respective work directories are at different directory-depths. So dependent on which flow i'm using a need to set the file reference to:

../../../my_library/referenced_file.txt
or
   ../../my_library/referenced_file.txt

i'd like to go up however many directories i need to until i reach "my_library"

Comment: You can use a short batch, that compares the last writing or reading times of the `referenced_file.txt` files and sets the current folder to the "younger" one.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to specify "go up however many levels you need in order to find `my_library`" in a path, because expanding such a path would require increasingly expensive recursion; in the common case of a nonexistent path, e.g. a typo, it could well walk all the way up to the root directory, and then have to search the entire filesystem, and returning "path not found" might take minutes or hours (or, if you've got NFS or Samba directory mounts set up, longer still).

You'll need to find some method of setting the path in question based on which process you're carrying out.

Comment: Definitely not worthwhile with a BAT or PowerShell file.

Comment: Thanks. I guess simply stating the full path is the easiest solution then - that is what i was initially trying to avoid as different projects each have their own structures etc

Comment: Well, if you don't mind a quick and dirty method, you could loop around a test for file existence, prepending '../' to the path each time the test fails, and giving up after ten iterations or however many makes sense in your environment. It'd be ugly and awful, especially in a batch file, but it would probably work.

Comment: Thanks again. Simple ideas do work well! I'm programming in VHDL and hiding that feature in a function is fairly straight forward.

Comment: Fair enough! If I've been of help to you, I'd be obliged to you for clicking the check mark you'll see beneath the vote up/down buttons alongside my answer. Thanks!